# Do Ajax after MVC Validation

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a form and in this form I have fields that are from a Model.
The form is a modal-dialog from bootstrap. When i click on the submit button all fields must be valid. This works!
Now i want to close the modal and refresh the page if the Model Validation is valid. Only the code does first the Ajax call and then the `ModelState.IsValid` in the Controller.

Ajax:

```
    $('#addAlertModal form').submit(function (e) {

        //TODO: if ModelState.IsValid in Controller
        refreshAlerts();
        closeAlertModal();
    });
```

Does somebody know what i can do about this? Or is this not possible?

EDIT:

Or is it possible to call Ajax functions inside the `if`:

```
        @if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) {
            //Call here the functions
            refreshAlerts(); //Error: The name 'refreshAlerts' does not exist in the current context
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "ManageAlert", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "addAlertModal", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "afterSubmit(data)"}))
{ ... }

function afterSubmit(data) {
    if (data.success === true) {
        refreshAlerts();
        closeAlertModal();
    }
}
```

And in the Model i return:

```
return Json(new { success = true });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
 $("#YourbuttonId").click(function () {

                       var validation = $("#FormId"); 
                        if (!validation.valid()) {
                              return false;
                         }
                         else {
                            refreshAlerts();
                           closeAlertModal();
                          }
                     });
```

Comment: That doesn't work! I have the requirements in the Model and not in the View! Now the validation will be always true.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ViewData.ModelState.IsValid` in a view

```
$('#addAlertModal form').submit(function (e) {

    @if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         refreshAlerts();
        closeAlertModal();

    }
});
```

Comment: Ok i now know that `@if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)` works, but now i can't call the ajax methods

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use an event so that when your validation is ok then you close the  page and refresh. you'll need to use a trigger that's all.

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean! Can you let me see it with some code?